# Android Emulator for Xamarin shows black screen

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

So as I downloaded Visual Studio 2017 and I decided to try Xamarin. So after I've created an Android project, and tried to launch it, it refuses to show me nothing but a black screen. It also tells me that: "There were deployment errors". Yet nothing is to be seen in the error box.

I hope someone can help me out.

Comment: Do you have Android Studio? I you have you could use their emulators. Maybe android player image is broken. Try to make an update in sdk.

Comment: What emulator are you launching? You may have visual studio Hyper-V emulators and Android sdk emulators.

Comment: Please post the build error log that shows in  the output window.

Comment: I am launching the Android Emulator for Visual Studio (Hyper-V).

2>Emulator is not ready to be used.
2>Deploy failed on VisualStudio_android-23_arm_phone
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: If you use Hyper-V, you could create a x86 architecture emulator and install the [`Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator(HAXM installer)`](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/debug-on-emulator/android-sdk-emulator/1-hardware-acceleration/).